# Highest point of the Planneralm 3D course (Robin Hood land)

Tags: archery, trails, alps, austria

I'll travel to the Planneralm next summer to shoot a little 3D. However, we've a person in the group which is a little bit concerned about the height (she has a shortness of breath if she goes too fast too high).

How high is the top-most point of the (3D-course-)trail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was there a few days ago. The highest point of the **3D course** was 1800 m and starts at 1600 m. Most of the hiking trails however go up to nearly 1900 m and one is even close to 2100 m.

Answer (score 3):

With the information on the [website](https://www.bogenschiessen.at/der-3d-parcours/) and [g00gle maps](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Planneralm/@47.4029557,14.2028556,15.98z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x47710ed26ef37dcf:0xe5c7eca8413a7063!5m1!1e4!6m1!1e1),
I think the whole parcour should be between 1500m and max. 1600m.